# REST service return not working

Tags: c#, rest, constructor, datacontract

I've got a rest service contract that used to work just fine returning an object of the class IdocEntity.

This is the working code for this:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "*",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "login/{userName}/{password}/{ip}"
        )]
    IdocEntity Login(string userName, string password, string ip);

public IdocEntity Login(string userName, string password, string ip)
    {
        [some checks]            
        try
        {
            userEntity = checkUSR(userName, password, ip, string.Empty); 

            if (userEntity == null)
            {
                ArgumentException exx = new ArgumentException("User not found");
                throw new WebFaultException<ErrorMessage>(new ErrorMessage(exx), HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }

            return userEntity;
        }
        catch (WebFaultException<ErrorMessage>)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<ErrorMessage>(new ErrorMessage(ex), HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

I also have another contract returning an object of the class Profile.

Profile extends from IdocEntity, and it's not working. Here's my object profile:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Profile : IdocEntity
{
  [a bunch of properties with [DataMember] on top of them]

    public Profile(Guid entityId) :
        base(entityId)
    { }

    [a bunch of methods to get or update a profile]
}
```

And here's the rest code for the one returning a profile

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "*",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "updateProfile"
        )]
    Profile UpdateProfile(string entityId, string mail, string telf, string fax, string direc);


public Profile UpdateProfile(string entityId, string mail, string telf, string fax, string direc)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityId))
            {

                Profile perfil = Profile.GetProfileByEntityId(new Guid(entityId));
                perfil.Mail = mail;
                perfil.Telephone = telf;
                perfil.Fax = fax;
                perfil.Direccion = direc;

                Profile.UpdateProfileDataByEntityId(perfil);
                return perfil;
            }
            else
            {
                ArgumentException exx = new ArgumentException("Error. No se encuentra el usuario.");
                throw new WebFaultException<ErrorMessage>(new ErrorMessage(exx), HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
        }

        catch (WebFaultException<ErrorMessage>)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<ErrorMessage>(new ErrorMessage(ex), HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }
```

Now, I changed the first one to return a Profile object, to get more info and it stopped working. I then checked the second one and it was failing too.

It does everything just fine, but my rest service is returning `0 No Response`

Both IdocEntity and Profile have their [DataContract] and [DataMember] stuff in, and the the IdocEntity used to work just fine.

Maybe it's worth saying that Profile has a property that is a Hashtable
EDIT: The problem is not the hashtable attribute, without it doesnt work either.

Some help would be nice, thanks :)

Comment: more code required in order to be able to help

Comment: I'll post more code, I've changed some things, I thought the Profile one was working but wasn't, so thats not the problem, I'll update with more info.

Comment: I've looked around and couldn't find anything special about rest services returning objects thant extend from another one, so I've no clue about what's different between both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. One of the properties on my Profile class was a DateTime I had initialized as

`DateTime bornDate = new DateTime()`

and on my update I wasn't giving any values to it.

I changed it to

`DateTime bornDate = DateTime.now;`

and now works perfectly